# SharePoint 2013 workflow issue

Tags: development, workflow

We are developing custom workflow in our SharePoint 2013 project using Visual studio 2013. We have got one issue while updating list items in the custom workflow.

`Modified By` field is changed to System Account while updating item. It is not done with elevated privilege or with user token. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `item.SystemUpdate()` when updating the item.

This will not cause the Modified By field to change.